# Python - parallel process calling main process function

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I am having some troubles with multiprocessing. Here's the basic scheme of my program:

- the main process
- a parallel process called from the main process
- the parallel process trying to call a function from the main process

  ```
  class MainProcess():
      def foo(self):
          # do something

      def main():
          p = ParallelProcess(self)
          p.start()


  class ParallelProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
      def __init__(self, mainProcess):
          multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
          self.mainProcess = mainProcess

      def run(self):
          self.mainProcess.foo()
  ```

My actual program is much more complicated, but this example explains the structure of my code perfectly. The error I get has something to do with pickle. 
As far as I understand I get this type of error because mainProcess is not pickable. However, I do not know which other pattern or code structure to use other than the one shown above. 
Any help would be very appreciated.

The exact error, as requested, is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 342, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 1370, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\workspace\Eyelink1.1\gcwindow_main.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\workspace\Eyelink1.1\gcwindow_main.py", line 9, in main
    wrapper.run() # start collecting data on a separate process
  File "C:\Users\user\workspace\Eyelink1.1\pylinkwrapper.py", line 149, in run
    exp.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 104, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 239, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 162, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 725, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

Comment: Please can you tell us the exact error message?

Comment: @SteveMayne I added the Traceback.

Answer (score 2):

To use `pickle` for your class, you need to define `__getstate__`, `__setstate__` behavior. [More information in docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances).

But (!) as far as I understood, this will not solve your actual problem. Cause in this case you will get new (deserialized) instance of `MainProcess` inside `ParallelProcess` and will not be able to call function in context of parent process.

Comment: or you can inherit from `object`